# Is there any way to list user defaults datas with swift?

Tags: swift

I am trying to do save datas like name, address with user default at main view controller. After saving data, I wanted to list all user default data at second view controller with tableview (PeopleViewController). I managed to save user default data with main view controller. But only last saved user default data can be showed at tableview while I would like to list all data at tableview. What am I doing wrong? Can you give an idea? Thank you in advance..

My second view controller / PeopleViewController

```
import UIKit

class PeopleListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    var names = [String]()
    var address = [String]()
    let storage = UserDefaults.standard

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let peopleData = storage.value(forKey: "people") as? Data

                   if peopleData != nil {

                       let decoder = JSONDecoder()

                       do {

                        let person = try decoder.decode(People.self, from: peopleData!)

                        names.append(person.name)
                        address.append(person.address)

                       }catch {
                           print(error)
                       }
                   }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         return names.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LocationCell",for: indexPath)

         cell.textLabel?.text = names[indexPath.row]
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = address[indexPath.row]


        return cell
    }
}
```

My main view controller

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var TextFields: [UITextField]!

        let storage = UserDefaults.standard

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            let peopleData = storage.value(forKey: "people") as? Data

            if peopleData != nil {

                let decoder = JSONDecoder()


                do {

                    TextFields[0].text = ""
                    TextFields[1].text = ""

                }catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }

        @IBAction func createButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

           let name = TextFields[0].text!
           let address = TextFields[1].text!


              let people = People(
                name: name,
                address: address
            )

            let encoder = JSONEncoder()

            do {
                let peopleData = try encoder.encode(people)

                storage.setValue(peopleData, forKey: "people")
                TextFields[0].text! = ""
                TextFields[1].text! = ""

            }catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

My People Model

```
import Foundation

struct People: Codable{
    var name: String
    var address: String
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, you are only storing one person in `UserDefaults`. Every time you create a new person, you are overwriting the previous value. To store many people, you need an `[People]`. When you decode and encode, you can encode the whole `[People]`.

```
// main VC
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    // first decode the array from the storage
    let array = storage.data(forKey: "people").map { try decoder.decode([People].self, from: $0) } ?? []
    array.append(people) // add the newly created person
    let newArrayData = try encoder.encode(array)

    storage.set(newArrayData, forKey: "people")
    TextFields[0].text! = ""
    TextFields[1].text! = ""

}catch {
    print(error)
}

// table VC
// you don't need two parallel arrays
var people: [People] = []
let storage = UserDefaults.standard

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    do {
    people = try storage.data(forKey: "people").map { try decoder.decode([People].self, from: $0) } ?? []
    } catch let error { 
        print(error) 
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return people.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LocationCell",for: indexPath)

     cell.textLabel?.text = people[indexPath.row].name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = people[indexPath.row].address


    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Sweeper, I fixed the error. I' ve started swift recently :)